# Theorems that deals only with critical metrics of Einstein-Hilbert like functional

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology

It is common that researchers study the critical metrics of Einstein-Hilbert like functional
$${\cal R^2}=\int_M|{\rm Ric}_g|^2dV_g,\quad \text{or}\quad {\cal r^2}=\int_M{\rm scal}_g^2dV_g$$
and deduce some results. **For example** Michael Anderson in his paper

*Anderson, Michael T.*, [**Extrema of curvature functionals on the space of metrics on 3-manifolds. II**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s005260000043), Calc. Var. Partial Differ. Equ. 12, No. 1, 1-58 (2001). [ZBL1018.53020](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1018.53020).

has proved the following:

> **Theorem 0.1.** Let $(N, g)$ be a complete $\cal R^2$ critical metric with non-negative
> scalar curvature. Then $(N,g)$ is flat.

I haven't read the full paper. My question is that how this theorem can be useful while it deals only with critical metrics? I mean how can one use this and similar results to deduce nice results that are true without critical metrics assumption?

I know that Einstein metrics are critical points of Einstein-Hilbert functional $r$ so I think one can replace critical metric with Einstein manifolds in similar theorems and the result will remain true. Is this the only possible application of these set of theorems that deals with critical metrics?

Comment: This paper grew out of a program developed by Anderson for proving the Geometrization Conjecture for 3-dimensional manifolds. His approach was to search for critical points of some functionals, prove that (if exist) they have constant sectional curvature. He was also planning to show that for a general 3-manifold there is a flow towards one of the critical points that degenerates in the process (never reaching the critical point), but obtaining a suitable decomposition of the manifold along spheres and tori as the result of such a degeneration. Perelman's work disrupted all these plans....

Comment: @MoisheKohan: thanks for clarifying  hidden angle. Ok, but there is a similar theorem that has been published in 2014. You mean all of these are along that program?

Comment: Could be. It is still interesting to find alternative approaches, which (if they work!) might provide further insights into geometry of 3-manifolds.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: further insights? I thought after Perelman work, 3-manifolds are fully understood from all angles?!

Comment: In a very broad sense, critical points may be interpreted as the "best" or "preferred" cases, see e.g. this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/366057/2002).

Comment: @C.F.G: It depends on what you mean by "understood". For instance, it is far from clear what geometric properties of hyperbolic metrics one can infer from the topological properties of the manifolds. There are partial results in this direction, some are obtained by looking at the Ricci flow.